# C++ boost thread delay

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I want to wait 1.5 seconds in a boost thread. Using boost::xtime I can wait an integer number of seconds:

```
// Block on the queue / wait for data for up two seconds.
boost::xtime_get(&xt, boost::TIME_UTC);
xt.sec++;
xt.sec++;
....
_condition.timed_wait(_mutex, xt)
```

How can I wait 1.5 seconds instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the following not work using the nanoseconds and seconds portion and increasing by 0.5 billion nanoseconds and adding a second which is 1.5 seconds

```
xt.sec++;
xt.nsec += 500000000;
_condition.timed_wait(_mutex, xt);
```